# Why is there an $E^2$-term in the expression for the polarization density in nonlinear optics

Tags: non-linear-optics

In nonlinear optics the polarization density can be expressed as $$P_i=\epsilon_0(X_{ii}^{(1)}E_i+X_{iji}^{(2)}E_jE_i+\dots)$$

As far as I know, $P$ arises from the dipole moment in materials, and $E$ is an applied electric field in this equation. Terms involving $E^2$ and $E^3$ cause the phenomenon of nonlinear optics. However, I don't understand why these $E^2, E^3 \dots$ terms appear in this equation? What's the physical meaning?

Comment: What's $X(1)$? And $X(2)$? Please make sure that your post is self-contained (i.e. comprehensible without reference to other resources).

Comment: It's for basically the same  reason why terms like $x^3$ show up in $\sin(x)=x-x^3/6+...$. It's a Taylor series.

Answer (score 3):

When an electric field $\mathbf{E}$ interacts with matter, it causes the atoms and molecules to distort and separate into dipole-like blobs, and these dipole blobs then increase the field strength. So, inside of the matter, the total electric field is actually the sum of two components: the external electric field $\mathbf{E}$, plus the electric field induced by the matter itself when it responds to the external field.

Traditionally, this total field times $\varepsilon_0$ is written as $\mathbf{D}=\varepsilon_0\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{E})$, where $\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{E})$ is the electric field generated by the matter as a function of $\mathbf{E}$, and is called the *polarization*.

Since $\mathbf{P}$ is a function of $\mathbf{E}$, we can Taylor expand $\mathbf{P}$ around the origin:
$$\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{E})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\nabla^n\mathbf{P})(\mathbf{0})\cdot\mathbf{E}^n}{n!},$$
where $\mathbf{E}^n=\mathbf{E}\otimes\mathbf{E}\otimes\mathbf{E}...$ is the $n^\text{th}$ outer product of $\mathbf{E}$, $(\nabla^n\mathbf{P})(\mathbf{0})$ is the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of $\mathbf{P}$ evaluated at the origin, and $\cdot$ is tensor contraction. Defining $\chi^{(n)}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0n!}(\nabla^n\mathbf{P})(\mathbf{0})$ and using the fact that in a non-[electret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret) material $\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$, we can rewrite this as

$$\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{E})=\varepsilon_0\sum_{n=1}^\infty\chi^{(n)}\cdot\mathbf{E}^n=\varepsilon_0\left(\chi^{(1)}\cdot\mathbf{E}+\chi^{(2)}:(\mathbf{E}\otimes\mathbf{E})\,+\,...\right)
\\
\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{E})=\varepsilon_0\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{E})=\varepsilon_0\left((\mathbf{1}+\chi^{(1)})\cdot\mathbf{E}+\chi^{(2)}:(\mathbf{E}\otimes\mathbf{E})\,+\,...\right)$$

where $\chi^{(n)}$ is the $n^\text{th}$ unitless *electric susceptibility tensor* (a tensor of rank $n+1$), and $\mathbf{1}$ is the $3\times3$ identity matrix.

In essence, the physical meaning is just a Taylor series of the matter field $\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{E})$. The linear term gives ordinary optics, and the quadratic and higher terms give rise to nonlinear optics.

When I learned nonlinear optics, I was initially confused and had the same questions as you have; as it turned out, the source of the confusion was actually not a question of physics, but rather was a problem with math: I didn't understand how Taylor series worked for vector functions of vector argument.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the dipole moment as analogous to a extending/compressing a spring (or rubber band), vis a vis Hooke's Law

$$ X = \frac{1}{k} F $$

As such, $P$ is analogous to the spring displacement $X$, applied $E$ is analogous to force $F$ applied to the spring, and susceptibility $\chi$ is analogous to inverse spring constant $\frac{1}{k}$.  In our case,

$$\textbf{P} = \epsilon_0\chi \textbf{E}.$$

For rest of the discussion, I will ignore the vector nature of $\textbf{E}$ and $\textbf{P}$ and simplify to scalar $E$ and $P$, with unit vector implied.

Thinking of the physical spring for a moment, if you stretch it too much, it reaches a limit and the spring constant starts changing.  Another words, the spring "constant" $k$ is no longer constant and becomes a function of the displacement $X$, or alternatively, a function of force $F$.

For example, let us assume that spring "constant" can be approximated as so,

$$\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{k_1} + \frac{1}{k_2} F.$$

Then the displacement equation becomes

$$ X = \frac{1}{k_1} F + \frac{1}{k_2} F^2.$$

Notice that in the final form, we have a $F^2$ but this can be a bit confusing because one multiplicand of $F^2$ is specifically for describing how the spring constant changes, while the other multiplicand is specifically to determine displacement. A more clear (but mathematically excessive) way of writing it would be 
$$ X = \frac{1}{k_1} F + \left(\frac{1}{k_2} F\right) F.$$

Now, consider our electric field case. In the same way a spring is limited in the displacement, an electric dipole is limited (by various mechanisms) in polarization.   In our case, our $\chi^{(1)}$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{k_1}$, and $\chi^{(2)}$ to $\frac{1}{k_2}$, thus 
$$\chi = \chi^{(1)} + \chi^{(2)} E.$$

And from that, we arrive at the familiar NL polarization (simplified) expression,

$$ P = \epsilon_0\chi^{(1)} E + \epsilon_0\chi^{(2)} E^2 $$

In the exotic case, where susceptibility of field in one direction (e.g. $E_x$) is affected by a field in another (e.g. $E_y$), we might get

$$ P_x = \epsilon_0\chi_{xx}^{(1)} E_x + \epsilon_0 \left(\chi_{xyx}^{(2)} E_y\right) E_x. $$

Here, polarization $P_x$ is created by presence of $E_x$, but the susceptibility is affected by the presence of $E_y.$  Nevertheless, this is lumped in (incorrectly, in my option) with the family of 2nd order nonlinear effects.

More complex susceptibility function require higher terms, causing higher order E field terms (e.g. $E^3$...) to appear.  Now, it is quite conceivable to instead describe nonlinear optics in terms of transcendental functions of E (e.g. tanh(E) or log(E) or sin(E) or whatever), but as @DumpsterDoofus notes, it has become de facto (for good reasons) to approximate the susceptibility as a Taylor expansion.